# Can't access some content on page using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium in a python script to login into a website where I can get an authorization key to access their API. I am able to login and navigate to the page where the authorization key is provided, I am using chrome driver for testing so I can see what's going on. When I get to the final page where the key is displayed, I can't find a way to access it. I can't see it in the page source, and when I try to access via the page element outer html, it doesn't print the value shown on the page. Here is a screenshot of what I see in the browser (I'm interested in accessing the content shown in response body):

[image]

this is the code snippet I am using to try to access the content:

```
auth_key = WebDriverWait(sel_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="responseBodyContent"]')))
print auth_key.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

and this is what the print statement returns:

```
<pre id="responseBodyContent"></pre>
```

I've also tried:

```
print auth_key.text
```

which returns nothing. Is there way I can extract this key from the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a custom wait to wait for the element and then wait for text. 
First, add a class, find element and then get `innerHTML` of the element. Finally, measure length of the string.
See my example below.

```
class element_text_not_empty(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
            if(len(element.get_attribute('innerHTML').strip())>0):
                return element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
            else:
                return False
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error while waiting: " + str(ex))
            return False

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
...
...
try:
    print("Start wait")
    result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(element_text_not_empty((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="responseBodyContent"]')))
    print(result)
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error: " + str(ex))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since attribute value is in json format for responseBodyContent try this

authkey_text = json.loads(auth_key.get_attribute)
print str(authkey_text)